# What are the control instructions and move instructions latency for Intel's newer architectures?

Tags: x86, intel, machine-code, micro-architecture

I am looking at the [Intel Architectures Optimization Reference Manual 2017](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/9e/bc/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) (Page 759). I am looking for Haswell and Skylake architectures. `MOV, PUSH, JMP, CALL` instructions are intentionally omitted in that table. No latency information is given. Why is that? Although, those instruction latency is given for the Atom processors on page 776.

Interestingly the [2012 optimization manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) from Intel has `MOV`, `PUSH` and `CALL` instructions latency.

Agner's [instruction tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) provides latency for `MOV` and `PUSH`, but skips for control instructions like `JMP` and `CALL`. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Branch prediction + speculative execution makes the concept of latency meaningless for control instructions.  There's no data dependency.  Latency from what to what?  If you mean latency from RSP to RSP in `call`, the stack engine makes that 0.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense for control instructions. However, an average latency over a longer period of time with some throughput values could have been given for control instructions. I understand that it would also be limited information in some sense.
But I expected some latency data for the control instructions.

Comment: Agner Fog has throughput and uop counts for control instructions, but **latency would be meaningless**.  I have no idea what you think "average latency over a longer period of time" would mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that latency is not really a meaningful metric in practice for control instructions, and for many types of mov instructions in isolation.

In the comments you mention:

> I was referring to Intel's manual for control instructions. What I
>   mean by average latency for control instructions is that we get some
>   data for number of instructions retired over a period of time and then
>   take time/(number of instructions).

When we talk about the *latency* of an instruction, we generally mean **the time in takes to produce a result from its input(s)**, and not how many results can be produced in a given period of time. It's the difference between it taking 9 months to make a baby (the latency) versus having 100 babies born in a month in a city (a throughput).

The usual way to measure latency is then to chain together a series of instructions where the output from one instruction is used as an input to the next. Since they are dependent, you get a latency measurement since they execute serially. For example, if you wanted to measure the latency of `add`, you'd could use a sequence like the following:

```
add eax, eax
add eax, eax
add eax, eax
...
```

Note how the output register `eax` is fed back in an input to the next `add`.

Now, control flow instructions don't have an obvious explicit "output" that can be fed back into their input. Their output is a change in the instruction flow, but it isn't clear how to feed that back into the next instruction. Furthermore, the whole mechanism of control flow is generally decoupled into a branch prediction engine which tries to steer the front end correctly long before control flow instructions are ever executed, further muddying the waters when it comes to latency.

At best you can talk about throughput for these constructs: modern Intel can generally execute *two branches per cycle*, at most one of which can be taken.

You run into the same problem with `mov` instructions to or from memory. Here, the output and input are clear, but they live in different domains (register vs memory). So you can't necessarily feed the output of a store instruction into a subsequent store instruction, since stores have a "memory" output but "register" input. What you can do is chain together pairs of load and store instructions on the same location and get a combined latency for the pair: this generally runs from 3 to 7 cycles on modern Intel depending on addressing mode and other factors.

For loads in particular, you can use the result of the load (register domain) in the address calculation for the next load, giving you a load-to-load-address latency (some people call this load-to-use, but I consider that confusing), which is generally 4 cycles at best on modern Intel, with 1 additional cycle needed each for complex addressing modes or vector loads.

For register to register moves, the latency is usually zero cycles (due to mov elimination), or 1 cycle when the mov cannot be eliminated.

Those issues are probably why you don't see latency figures for those constructs in Intel's guides, or even in other guides like Agner's.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorant comment (I have deleted it). I was wrong about latency. Thanks for your take on the issue.

Comment: No worries, this division between latency and throughput has become much more important as CPUs execute multiple instructions in parallel based on data flow, rather than the old days of one-instruction-at-a-time where latency and (inverse) throughput were the same thing.

Comment: load-use latency describes the more general case where address -> data latency is part of a dependency chain, and the loaded data is used as an input for something other than another load.  e.g. `imul rax, rdx, 1234` / `imul rcx, [rax]` / ... stuff dependent on rcx.  Using a load result as an address right away (aka pointer chasing) is just a convenient way to measure load-use latency.